# REST filter Condition for find using Where filter with and/or conditions

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, strongloop, loopback

I'm trying to filter user data based on skill set & location with both [and] and [or] together on where filter. My Mongo query would be like this:

```
    {
    "where": {
        "and": [{
            "or": [{
                "location": "Hyderabad"
            }, {
                "location": "Mumbai"
            }]
        }, {
            "or": [{
                "skill_set": "Java"
            }, {
                "skill_set": "Database"
            }]
        }]
    }
}
```

I'm trying to achieve the above mongo query through REST filter. So far My REST filter is like this:

```
filter[where][and][0][or][0][location]=Hyderabad&filter[where][and][0][or][1][location]=Mumbai&filter[where][or][0][skill_set]=Java&filter[where][or][1][skill_set]=Database
```

My console doesn't show any error but I'm not getting any data even though my DB has data. Is something wrong with my REST filter?

Answer (score 0):

I dont see a problem in your code. But it can be made simple like this.

We can use `inq` instead of `or`.

```
{
    "where": {
        "and": [{
            "location": { "inq": [ "Hyderabad", "Mumbai" ] }
        }, {
            "skill_set": { "inq": [ "Java", "Database" ] }
        }]
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm asking about REST filter query